# Mejorar entorno de desarrollo. vpn ip@domain Windows Server 2012 r2 para .net angular

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-server-2012, vpn, angular11, github-actions

Me encuentro desarrollando un sistema interno para banca, el cual consume diferentes servicios para autentificacion, transacciones... etc, mediante apirest y protobuffer, con las tecnologias de java,.net y angular.
Mi problema es que por ejemplo si necesito probar algunos roles debo conectarme a la vpn y luego autentificarme con una cuenta de active directory en cierta ip@dominio luego ejecutar npm start que desencadena un scrip para cierto puerto, con un proxy.conf.js para los cors y diferentes configuraciones, al igual que la api principal esta configurada con cors etc, entonces hacer cambios y compilar cada vez toma mucho tiempo, por lo que decidi hacer cambios en mi pc personal y compilar en modo produccion para subirlo a github y asi pegarlo en el IIS siendo esto menos tardado, pero **estoy buscando una mejor manera de hacer esto cada vez que hago cambios.** Lo unico que encontre es algo relacionado a GitHub actions pero no estoy muy familiarizado.

Tambien cabe aclarar que solo me hace falta hacer cambios en el frontend que esta en angular, por lo que las variables de entorno estan aputando a la api en produccion, en fin muchas gracias espero alguien me ayude.

Comment: Solo podrian decirme, ¿si es posible hacerlo con github actions o algo asi?, Me estresa mucho trabajar como lo venido haciendo :'u

Comment: Necesitas explicar más la pregunta y dar más contexto, si me esfuerzo por entender, creo que lo que quieres es crear un ambiente de CI pero tus recursos están en una VPN, lo que puedes hacer es crear una imagen de Docker que se conecte a la VPN y configurarla como imagen en el GitHub actions.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @Ali mil gracias por comentar, no se si podrias volver a leer mi pregunta y si no intentare tu sugerencias.

Comment: Aún no está bien formulada la pregunta y me di mil vueltas jaja, pero lo que te dije te puede servir, configuras una imagen que se encargue de hacer todo tu trabajo manual como si se ejecutara desde una red externa, si la imagen funciona, fácilmente puede correr esa imagen con GitHub actions.